# Collect email address from a web form on a simple website

Tags: forms, email

I've created a dead simple landing page, with a text-field form to collect email addresses. But the thing is, there's no database, no backend of any kind, so how I hook up the form to actually collect the inputed data when it's submitted?!?

I've done this a bunch of times in Rails apps or on Wordpress, is there a service to allow me to do this in a normal static webpage? Maybe a script to route to a Google spreadsheet or something?

This is not a wordpress site etc. so I can't use a plugin for a certain platform, just a totally standard, vanilla website.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's a service called Cloudstitch that makes it really easy to post data to a Google spreadsheet.